Unknown video format in v4l2 --- is there an easy way to add support?
I've got a infrared webcam, which has guvc video support. Unfortunately, when I connect it to a Linux PC, I get this in the logs and the camera is unusable (although still produces a /dev/video device):
[ 9673.358195] uvcvideo 3-5.4.3:1.1: Unknown video format e436eb7b-524f-11ce-9f53-0020af0ba770
[ 9673.358200] usb 3-5.4.3: Found UVC 1.00 device IR VIDEO (1fc9:009b)
[ 9673.358204] uvcvideo 3-5.4.3:1.1: No supported video formats found.
[ 9673.358206] uvcvideo 3-5.4.3:1.1: Failed to initialize the device (-22).

Some web searching shows that the GUID is probably referring to RGB565. Some more shows me the list of GUIDs supported by uvcvideo, and this one is not on the list even though RGB565 does appear to be supported through the UVC_GUID_FORMAT_RGBP GUID.
I really don't want to have to build my own kernel driver. Is there a way to override the GUID supplied by the device so that I can spoof it into working?

TBH I'm not familiar, but have you tried things like the one mentioned in https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1968122&sid=18b7c842ea4dafad0b1e8df7d0a82b86#p1968122
